# IE.document.*ANYTHING* throws 430 error

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, browser-automation, vba

I have this code running on one computer, but not another.  I hit an error whenever I try to call any of the following.

```
"InternetExplorer.document.getElementById("test")

"HTMLDocument.getElementsByid("test")

"HTMLDoc.all.quickSearchForm.Value = "
```

I've tried all different methods of interacting with HTML elements in an excel macro, many work great on my home computer but not the production machine.

I've checked the following so far,

Working Machine is: WIN10 PRO / OFFICE 2010 - logged in as admin
Not working is: WIN7 ENT / OFFICE 2010 - logged as user?

Both machines have reference libraries installed and active in VB
-stdole2.TLB
-mshtml.TLB

Website:  https://sfbay.craigslist.org is set as trusted in IE both boxes.

Here is my complete code working on one box and not the other.

```
    Sub TEST4()
'
' TEST3 Macro
'
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim myZip As Long
Dim siteZip As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim gender As Object
Dim btnGo As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
URL = "https://sfbay.craigslist.org/"
IE.navigate (URL)
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
Set Vehicle = IE.document.getElementById("query") 'this is where I hit error everytime
Vehicle.Value = "Corvette"


End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have `Vehicle` declared in the shown routine - what is this variable?

Comment: It was <Dim Vehicle = object >. Should I try as <long>?

Comment: Ok, clearly I'm not getting what I was looking for from this thread.  The above code works on some machines and not others.  How to a debug for that?

Comment: Do you have references to `Microsoft HTML Library` as well as `InternetExplorer`

Comment: I can see ref library files: VB -stdole2.TLB -mshtml.TLB on both machines, and they are both selected in VB > Tools > References > available references.